# Truncation of a Sobolev function is still Sobolev

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a regular domain (compact boundary $C^1$) e let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$. Let $tr(u) \equiv \alpha$.

I would like to prove that the truncated function $$\bar{u}=u \chi_{\{u < \alpha \}}+\alpha \chi_{\{u \geq \alpha \}}$$ is still a Sobolev function with $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\chi_{\{u <1\}}$ and $tr(\bar{u})=1$.

I tried to apply the direct definition with the existence of weak derivative but I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: L'esame di istituzioni si avvicina...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the case.

Note that $u-\alpha\in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
It is a known result that $\max(v,0)\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ if $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$,
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384448/stampacchia-theorem-nabla-gu-gu-nabla-u?rq=1)
for example (using $G(x)=\max(x,0)$), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372465/how-to-prove-that-u-v-in-w-01-2-omega-if-u-in-w-01-2-omega?rq=1).

Using
$$
\bar u = \max(u-\alpha,0)+\alpha
$$
it follows that $\bar u\in H^1(\Omega)$.

**old answer** (before an important correction was made in the original post):

No, this is not the case.

We choose $d=1$, $\Omega=(0,2\pi)$ and the function
$$
 u(x) = 2+\sin(x).
$$
Clearly, $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\alpha=2$.
However, $\bar u$ is not continuous and has a jump at $x=\pi$:
$$
 \bar u(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
  1 & x\in (0,\pi)
  \\
  2+sin(x) & x\in [\pi,2\pi)
 \end{cases}
$$
Therefore it is not a Sobolev function.
(Note that for $d=1$ the functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ are continuous.)

Comment: Sorry I made a stupid mistake:now the truncated function should be continous in the 1 dimensional case everytime.

Comment: ok I answered the new question as well.